Export Eigen template instantiation from a module
I'm trying to speed up my compilation:
https://www.reddit.com/r/cpp/comments/1fmbdl6/comment/lolznmk/?context=3
Inspired by
https://gitlab.com/libeigen/eigen/-/issues/1920
I'm trying to make this example work:
math.ixx
module; 

#define EIGEN_NO_STATIC_ASSERT
#include <Eigen/Core>

export module math;

export typedef Eigen::Matrix4d M;

main.cpp
import math;

void main() {
    //Eigen::Matrix4f m;
    M m;

    m.setZero();

    m = m * m * m * m * m * m * m * m * m * m * m * m * m * m * m * m * m * m * m * m * m * m * m * m * m * m * m * m * m * m * m * m * m * m * m * m * m * m * m * m * m * m * m * m * m * m * m * m;

Currently, it fails (VS22) with call_assignment_no_alias, which I probably need to export.
Any easy, elegant way to export instantiation of Eigen types?
